# spring boot unit test active profiles

Tags: spring-boot-test

spring boot `main` uses `mysql` in `application.properties` and `test` uses `h2` in `application-ut.properties`. However, when run tests, in console it says `active profile: ut`, but `test` still uses `datasource application.properties`. And once I remove `application.properties` tests would use `h2`.

**Test**:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles(value = "ut")
```

**POM:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**application-ut.properties:**

```
app.name=My app.
server.context-path=/
spring.jackson.serialization.indent-output=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

**application.properites:**

```
app.name=my app
server.context-path=/
spring.jackson.serialization.indent-output=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

**Console**:

```
10:03:37.570 [main] INFO  com.example.demo.RestControllerTest 641 logStartupProfileInfo  - The following profiles are active: ut
10:03:37.726 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext 582 prepareRefresh  - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6b53bcc2: startup date [Fri Jun 23 10:03:37 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
10:03:37.804 [background-preinit] INFO  org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version 30 <clinit>  - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.4.Final
10:03:38.225 [main] INFO  org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate 165 multipleStoresDetected  - Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
**[And then it loads datasource in application.properties]**
```